# Does a modern browser also cache files referenced in files that are in the manefest

Tags: ios, html, web-applications, html5-appcache

I am wondering if browsers save a 'Google Font' that is mentioned in a CSS file that is mentioned in a Cache Manifest? If not, what are the reasons for doing so?

Answer (score 0):

No they do not. The simple reason for this being that they can't know whether the file is static or dynamic or actually anything about it, thus it would be bound to cause trouble if they did. If you wish to use Google Fonts in an offline app you will have to download the files by hand by opening the relevant file in a couple of different browsers and combining the CSS into one declaration.

For example in chrome you get this line

```
src: local('Roboto Regular'), local('Roboto-Regular'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/roboto/v11/2UX7WLTfW3W8TclTUvlFyQ.woff) format('woff');
```

(source: http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto)

whereas for IE

```
src: url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/roboto/v11/5YB-ifwqHP20Yn46l_BDhA.eot);
src: local('Roboto Regular'), local('Roboto-Regular'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/roboto/v11/5YB-ifwqHP20Yn46l_BDhA.eot) format('embedded-opentype'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/roboto/v11/2UX7WLTfW3W8TclTUvlFyQ.woff) format('woff');
```

is served. So download all the different versions and then combine it like in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9569320/1266242